# how to run stored procedure in oracle with loop

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, cursor, procedure

i want to call the procedure through anon block like
begin t_maha_del_22_06_p('22.06.2020');end;
but i run it once and want call with loop to take a large date time
like from first 1-st to 15-th august. How can i do it ?

```
create table t_maha_delete_22_06
(dt date,text varchar2(100));


create or replace procedure my_sch.t_maha_del_22_06_p(p_dt in date default trunc(sysdate) -1) as
begin
delete from t_maha_delete_22_06
where trunc(dt) = p_dt;
commit;

insert into t_maha_delete_22_06
select 
trunc(p_dt) dt,
'blablabla' text from dual 
commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in loop as follows:

```
begin 
For dt in (select date '2020-08-01' + level - 1 as dates
           From dual 
           Connect by level <= date '2020-08-15' - date '2020-08-01')
Loop
t_maha_del_22_06_p(dt.dates);
End loop;
end; 
/
```